# Group by column in Pandas and count Unique values in each group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count, aggregate

I'm trying to use groupby in pandas to group by a variable column and count the number of times a value shows up in the each group.

For example, using this group:

```
d = {'Period': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
'Result': ['True','True','False','True','False','True','False','True','True','False','False','True','False','True','False','False']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.sort_values(by=['Period'], inplace=True)
print(df)
```

I'd like to count how many times 'True' or 'False' shows up in each period. Outputting something like this:

```
Period
1 : 2 True, 2 False
2 : 2 True, 1 False
3 : 0 True, 4 False
3 : 3 True, 1 False
```

The problem I'm having is that none of the methods in the examples I found do quite that.

`.count()` alone just counts the # of entries in each period

`.nunique()` returns the number of unique entries

`.unique()` returns the unique entries that exist but doesn't count them...

If you run this full example code you'll see what I mean:

```
#create dataframe
d = {'Period': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
'Result': ['True','True','False','True','False','True','False','True','True','False','False','True','False','True','False','False']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.sort_values(by=['Period'], inplace=True)
print(df)

#group by and print counts 
print(df.groupby('Period')['Result'].count())
print(df.groupby('Period')['Result'].nunique())
print(df.groupby('Period')['Result'].unique())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas-crosstab):

```py
print(pd.crosstab(df["Period"], df["Result"]))
```

Prints:

```
Result  False  True
Period             
1           2     2
2           1     3
3           4     0
4           1     3
```

Comment: Well that is a thing of beauty!

Answer (score 1):

Using `collections.Counter`:

```
df.groupby('Period')['Result'].apply(Counter).fillna(0).unstack()
```

output:

```
        True  False
Period             
1        2.0    2.0
2        3.0    1.0
3        0.0    4.0
4        3.0    1.0
```

Using `value_counts`:

```
df.groupby('Period')['Result'].value_counts().unstack().fillna(0)
```

output:

```
Result  False  True
Period             
1         2.0   2.0
2         1.0   3.0
3         4.0   0.0
4         1.0   3.0
```

Comment: This is great too, I actually liked that it produced a long format version initially.

Comment: Just remove unstack @JohnConor